# ImportError: libboost_python37.so.1.68.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory while importing pyopenvdb

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, openvdb

While importing the library pyopenvdb, I keep the getting the following error

```
ImportError: libboost_python37.so.1.68.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried running the following commands:

```
apt-get install libboost-python-dev
apt-get install libboost-numpy-dev
apt-get install python-dev
apt-get install python-numpy
```

from the link: https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/issues/845

I also tried installing `libboost-all-dev`.
However, none of the above steps have resolved the error.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked which library files are available with `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libboost_python*`? Do they actually match with your Python version?